# Which Mercurial plugin should I use for IntelliJ

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea

Which of the hg plug-ins has:

- the least hassles
- causes the least trouble
- is prettiest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't claim to have tried a wide variety, but, what's wrong with [hg4idea](http://www.ohloh.net/p/hg4idea)...?

Answer (score 3):

In regards to the "don't use one" response - this is hardly adequate. What if I use my IDE to do a refactoring that renames a file? Without IDE/source control integration, the file rename is made without regards to source control, and then Mercurial (or whatever else) thinks a file went missing and a new one appeared. Then you have to go back to wrangle with the source control to sort things out.

Comment: Although I agree with the statement as it is, this is what is great about git. (And AFAIK earlier versions of hg). It is silly you have to tell the version control about file moves and renames. I like how TortoiseHg has a guess option, but I love how when using git I totally can ignore this mundane task

Comment: I just started using git. It seems a little complicated, but it seems like the complicated parts all have their reasons for being. In regards to git automatically figuring out file renames, I just made a commit where it totally missed to file renames. I had changed 1 or 2 lines in a 10 line file.

Answer (score 3):

JetBrains seems to [have chosen](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2010/06/pycharm-build-96-438-is-available/) [hg4idea-luciad](http://plugins.jetbrains.net/plugin/?idea&id=4624) for its upcoming Python editor ([PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)) and it is now more active than [hg4idea](http://plugins.jetbrains.net/plugin/?idea&id=3370)

It looks like a leader is on the way :-)

Answer (score -6):

To answer your question: The best IDE PlugIn is don't use on.

I think IDE integration is not necessary when working with a [DVCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control). When working in a centralized System, it is reasonable for the purpose of automatic check out on edit. However, I like keeping things separate. I don't want my IDE cluttered up. I don't see any benefits in using a plug-in compared to a standalone solution (that I keep running on a second monitor etc. ).

I am fine with TortoiseHG and the command line for more complicated tasks.

Comment: I completely and utterly disagree. Having to switch back-and-forth between IDE and folder view is distracting and unnecessary.

Comment: I agree with the comment above.  Having the option to pop to the cmd line is fine, but you really want to take advantage of the refactoring abilities of the IDE and you want it to automatically handle SCM for you in those refactorings.

Comment: Why so many downvotes for this? TortoiseHG + command line simply rocks. There is nothing that it can not do when it comes to complex situations and fine tasks. Yes, integration with an IDE can be good but even now (Oct 2014) there is no Mercurial plugin for any IDE that can cover all situation (unfortunately)